# Calling c++ function in a struct with C#

Tags: c#, dllimport, interopservices

i have a c++ dll. i have to use this dll in c# code. in this dll:

```
struct UserRecord
{
  int               login;
  //some properties here
}
struct CServerInterface
{
  int         __stdcall ClientsAddUser(UserRecord *inf);
  //some other functions here
}
```

How can i call a function in a struct? I try this:

```
[DllImport("WebRegistration.dll")]
public extern static int ClientsAddUser(ref UserRecord inf);

public struct UserRecord
{
//properties here
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  UserRecord user = new UserRecord();
  ClientsAddUser(ref user);
}
```

throws exception: "Unable to find an entry point named 'ClientsAddUser' in DLL".

I suppose that if this function was not in a struct, i would not throw an exception.

Comment: Yeah, that is never going to work. As it is C++, you need to find out the mangled name (if that is the problem). You may have more luck exporting `CServerInterface` as a COM object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbee, but try this;
Make CServerInterface and UserRecord, "public class". An example;

```
public class CServerInterface() {int __stdcall ClientsAddUser(UserRecord *inf);}
```